# RXJS Get Current Value of a ReplaySubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I am trying to pull the current value from a ReplySubject on login. On subscribe in the current flow, the previous value is returned instead of a the current value. So the stuff received is the previous stuff at login and not the current stuff. Is there a way to get the current value of the observable on subscribe in the ReplaySubject without having to resort to a BehaviorSubject?

**stuff.service.ts:**

```
 private _stuffSubject = new ReplaySubject<any>();
 private _stuff$: Observable<any> = this._someSubject.asObservable();

  get stuff$ () {
   return this._stuff$;
  }

  private fetchStuff () {
    return this.http.get('/stuff/current')
      .map(data =>  {
        return data.json()
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.debug(this.constructor.name, 'handled error ->', err.message);
        return Observable.of(false);
      })
      .map(stuff => {
        this._stuffSubject.next(stuff);
      })
  }
```

**stuff.component.ts:**

```
this.stuffService.stuff$
  .subscribe(({stuff1, stuff2, stuff3}) => {
    this.stuff1 = `${stuff1}`;
    this.stuff2 = `${stuff2}`;
    this.stuff3 = `${stuff3}`;
  });
```

Comment: You can always subscribe to `_stuffSubject` to get its current buffer but you won't be able to tell when it emitted all its items.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the buffer size to 1:

```
private _stuffSubject = new ReplaySubject<any>(1);
```

Comment: `ReplaySubject(1)` is like `BehaviourSubject()`, but I think that it buffers the first and throws away subsequent (until subscribed, then the buffer is able to take another)?

Comment: Hi @asmmahmud, you are quite correct the buffer stores the last value.

Comment: ReplaySubject allows you to buffer [n] number of previous values: const mySubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(2) will buffer 2 previous values...

Comment: Its actually not quite the same, ```BehaviorSubject``` will resolve with a value for the first time even if its an undefined value and ```ReplaySubject``` will not resolve until value is emitted